# Perfom a one-way ANOVA using rpsychi (R) and the subsequent post-hoc pair-wise comparisons

Tags: r, anova

I have 4 samples, represented by their means and standard deviations. If I consider a sample size for all of them as 100, how can I perform a one-way ANOVA using the library of rpsychi in R?

The samples are all normal distributed and independent.

These are their values:

> S1: mean1=5.5, sd1=0.6
>
> S2: mean2=5.6, sd2=0.5
>
> S3: mean3=5.9, sd3=0.5
>
> S4: mean4=6.1, sd4=0.6

How can I perform subsequently the post-hoc pair wise comparison (Tukey-HSD) using R as well??

Comment: Did you look at the help in rpsychi? Specifically for `ind.oneway.second`? Further, this question is probably too similar to your other one, which was asked and answered. http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/102703/601. Your Tukey HSD test statistic calculation is easy and can be looked up online. All you need to know in R is that the p-value from the studentized range distribution (*q*) can be obtained with `ptukey`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. John, yes, I checked ind.oneway.second of the pfsychi help pdf. However, I tried several times with no succeess introducing my data. I don't know how to write perfectly the code to perform this ANOVA. So I am asking if somebody knows the exact code of my example, and in that way, learn it. Thanks

Comment: Put in what you tried then. The site isn't about just giving an answer but helping people learn. If we don't know how you're failing at it then you won't learn. And if you don't show them your efforts people are often reluctant to assist. Further, if it's just about entering R commands then this is the wrong forum and it should be on StackOverflow with an R tag.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently discover a post in other forum with some of my own concerns:
http://www.wenda.io/questions/2570717/anova-in-r-using-summary-data.html

It solved partially what I needed. Applying the code published in that web to my data:

```
mean <- c(5.5,5.6,5.9,6.1)
sd <- c(0.6,0.5,0.5,0.6)
n <- c(100,100,100,100)
q2data.frame <- data.frame(mean,sd,n)
library(rpsychi)
with(q2data.frame, ind.oneway.second(mean,sd,n))
```

I get the next ANOVA table:

```
$anova.table
                SS  df    MS      F
Between (A)  22.75   3 7.583 24.863
Within      120.78 396 0.305       
Total       143.53 399             

$omnibus.es
      etasq etasq.lower etasq.upper 
      0.159       0.094       0.219 

$raw.contrasts
    mean.diff  lower  upper   std
1-2      -0.1 -0.254  0.054 0.078
1-3      -0.4 -0.554 -0.246 0.078
1-4      -0.6 -0.754 -0.446 0.078
2-3      -0.3 -0.454 -0.146 0.078
2-4      -0.5 -0.654 -0.346 0.078
3-4      -0.2 -0.354 -0.046 0.078

$standardized.contrasts
        es  lower  upper   std
1-2 -0.181 -0.459  0.097 0.141
1-3 -0.724 -1.002 -0.446 0.141
1-4 -1.086 -1.364 -0.808 0.141
2-3 -0.543 -0.821 -0.265 0.141
2-4 -0.905 -1.183 -0.627 0.141
3-4 -0.362 -0.640 -0.084 0.141

$power
 small medium  large 
 0.363  0.993  1.000
```

Does anybody know how can I get the p-value of the ANOVA analysis? Moreover, how can I perform a TukeyHSD?

Answer (score 0):

Use library(asbio). This will give you t(s), mean differences, upper and lower bounds, HLSD Diff Lower Upper Decision Adj. p-value decision, and adjusted p-value.

```
 #pairwise comparisons
 library(asbio)
 bonf <- pairw.anova(data$dv, data$group, method="tukey") #also try "bonf" or "lsd"
 print(tukey)
 #plot(tukey) #can plot the CFs
```